# What does "datum (sed) non concessum" mean?

Tags: phrase-meaning, latin

I've encountered the phrase *datum (sed) non concessum* in various English-language books and articles such as:

- [The Beauty of God's House](http://www.evolutionnews.org/2015/01/theologically_s092621.html), quoted in [Theologically Speaking, What Intelligent Design Is and What It Isn't](http://www.evolutionnews.org/2015/01/theologically_s092621.html)
- [Pistrina Liturgica](http://pistrinaliturgica.blogspot.com/2013/11/the-rite-stuff.html)
- [Theology in the Russian Diaspora](https://books.google.com/books?id=cvs8AAAAIAAJ&pg=PA123&lpg=PA123&dq=datum%20non%20concessum&source=bl&ots=BpE8M9Mlvh&sig=FkIYCE7kdivzA8lD2XofQ4iKTd4&hl=en&sa=X&ei=S823VMC4Joa-ggSPuoPIBA&ved=0CDUQ6AEwBA#v=onepage&q=datum%20non%20concessum&f=false)
- [‘A Designer Universe?’: An Exchange](http://www.nybooks.com/articles/archives/2000/jan/20/a-designer-universe-an-exchange/) (variant: *concessum non datum*)
- [The Bishop Goes to the University](https://books.google.com/books?id=ue6v3B73SzoC&pg=PA96&lpg=PA96&dq=datum%20non%20concessum&source=bl&ots=SxAhOleo5M&sig=LYNVPo14uXUL0D3Caub572O6wRk&hl=en&sa=X&ei=6dG3VLjrDsHZgwSvvYOoAw&ved=0CDIQ6AEwAw#v=onepage&q=datum%20non%20concessum&f=false)

It's clear that *datum* and *concessum* are passive past participles in Latin; *datum* can mean 'given' and *concessum* can mean 'conceded' or 'withdrawn' among [other possibilities](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/concessus#Latin).

So the phrase would seem to mean something like, "if we grant the preceding proposition for the sake of argument, without actually conceding that it's true, ..."

For [example](https://books.google.com/books?id=cvs8AAAAIAAJ&pg=PA123&lpg=PA123&dq=datum%20non%20concessum&source=bl&ots=BpE8M9Mlvh&sig=FkIYCE7kdivzA8lD2XofQ4iKTd4&hl=en&sa=X&ei=S823VMC4Joa-ggSPuoPIBA&ved=0CDUQ6AEwBA#v=onepage&q=datum%20non%20concessum&f=false),

> But allowing for the moment the truth of this hypothesis, *datum non concessum*, how is this episcopal collegiality supposed to have shown itself?

[Another](https://books.google.com/books?id=ue6v3B73SzoC&pg=PA96&lpg=PA96&dq=datum%20non%20concessum&source=bl&ots=SxAhOleo5M&sig=LYNVPo14uXUL0D3Caub572O6wRk&hl=en&sa=X&ei=6dG3VLjrDsHZgwSvvYOoAw&ved=0CDIQ6AEwAw#v=onepage&q=datum%20non%20concessum&f=false):

> However, the critical question was ... One might argue that ...
>   All right, *datum non concessum* the issue still remained as to why ...

And the other links show similar constructions. Is my understanding (which is based on the meanings of the individual words and on context) correct? Can anyone point me to a standard reference that describes the usage of the phrase?

**P.S.** There is some question as to whether this counts as an English phrase (idiom), or only a Latin one. (Actually I don't have evidence that the phrase is used in Latin, but that's not the main point.)

That's an open question, but in my favor, there are currently 4850 Google results for "datum sed non concessum". Even given that many of these are duplicates and not all are in English, nevertheless a good many of them appear to be unique, English-language pages. Usage does seem to be concentrated in circles of Catholic theology.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about Latin, not English. Educated writers are free to add any non-English expression to their prose, but we are not required to weigh in on such, nor is it appropriate for us to do so.

Comment: The short answer is that *concessum non datum*, which can be translated simply as *granted, not given*, is a rhetorical tool which offers a concession to a premise of the opposition, serving to strengthen the argument later. You may find the Italian formulation *dato, non concesso*, also meaning to agree for the sake of argument, to be more common. A less pretentious way to say it in English would be [*granted* or *given that*](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/148715), or *I will stipulate*.

Comment: @choster "Given, (but) not granted" or "given, (but) not conceded" surely? But yes, it's used to say "I'm not conceding that point, but if it that point was true then..." before arguing how your general case is correct even if that point was true.

Comment: @Robusto Some Latin phrases have become idioms in English. Would you reject a question about _per se_, _prima facie_, or _q.e.d._?

Comment: @Robusto: I disagree... It is about Latin, **and** English. This phrase appears to be used in English just as "sina qua non" or "QED" are. Yes, it's Latin, as are many other English phrases. If you assert that the phrase is not well-known enough in English communication be counted as on-topic, please cite your data to support that assertion. I'll add mine to the question.

Comment: Interesting, Google Ngrams can't find _datum non concessum_.

Comment: @Barmar: I thought that was odd too. Did it only recently start being used in English? Not even *datum sed non concessum* is in there.

Comment: @LarsH That's what I was wondering, but it seems weird that a Latin phrase would suddenly come into use. I assume that the Latin set phrases that we have are due to their historical use.

Comment: @Barmar: I would if they involved an analysis based on Latin grammar. Also, the ones you mention are *way* more frequently encountered than *datum non concessum*.

Comment: @Robusto: I *included* a cursory analysis of the Latin meaning of the phrase, as relevant background information, but my question is not *about* the Latin meaning. It's about the English meaning. Regarding your second sentence, can you be explicit about how objective measures of occurrence of *datum (sed) non concessum* establish that it is not an English phrase?

Comment: @choster: Thanks for your comment (answer). Do you have any references?

Comment: @LarsH: If you don't think difference of degree can be relevant, try an electric shock from a 9v battery and one from a bolt of lightning.

Comment: @Robusto: A valid point (*datum et concessum*). Yet the comparison doesn't imply that a 9v battery is inadequate to power a smoke detector. Nor does "X is used way less than Y," by itself, establish that X is not English.

Comment: @LarsH: I thought we had already established that Latin is not English.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/20305/discussion-between-larsh-and-robusto).

Comment: A Google Books search finds the phrase _datum non concessum_ in two English-language books: [_Theology in the Russian Diaspora_](https://books.google.com/books?id=cvs8AAAAIAAJ&pg=PA123&dq=%22datum+non+concessum%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=tdroVOGJDJe6ogSMmYKgDw&ved=0CCIQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=%22datum%20non%20concessum%22&f=false) (1989) and [_The Bishop Goes to the University_](https://books.google.com/books?id=ue6v3B73SzoC&pg=PA96&dq=%22datum+non+concessum%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=tdroVOGJDJe6ogSMmYKgDw&ved=0CCgQ6AEwAQ#v=onepage&q=%22datum%20non%20concessum%22&f=false) (2003)—not much of a showing.